# How to subtract a number from a variable that has a number value (python)

Tags: python

Sorry if This is obvious, I'm pretty new to python but find a great interest in it.

So basically I'm making this game-ish? (It's more of just a review of what I can do for myself) and I'm trying to make a money system and when you buy something, you subtract 50 from money (money = 5000). The way I did this was: `money = money + 50`. But it does not work because money is already assigned to 5000, so I was stuck on subtracting 50 from it.

Whole code:

```py
#balance, Make a 'difficulty' option so that the user can set their money
def balance():
 global money
 money = 5000 
 
def costa_tycoon_welcome_screen():
 print("Welcome to Costa Tycoon!")
 print("------------------------")
 balance() 
 print(money)

def costa_tycoon(): 
 print("Welcome to Costa Tycoon!")
 print("------------------------")
 print("Hire worker for $50 (1)")
 print("------------------------")
 options = input()
 if options == '1':
   print("------------------------")
   balance()
   money = money + 50 
   print("Current Balance:", money)
 

costa_tycoon()
```

Comment: You forgot `global money` in `costa_tycoon()`.

Comment: Hmmmmm... Somehow, `subtract 50 from money` and `money = money + 50` don't quite add up in my dictionary...

Comment: BTW, in order to actually make a variable global, you need to declare it **globally** (i.e., outside of any function scope). Inside a function, you can declare it `global`, but you only really need to do this when you want to **change** the value of that variable inside that function.

Comment: within the if conditional options == '1' you call balance, which resets money to 5000.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I don't believe that's correct. Declaring a variable `global` and assigning it a value is enough to create a global variable. Demo: https://ideone.com/N6BSHI

Answer (score 0):

```
def balance():    
    global money
    money = 5000 


def costa_tycoon_welcome_screen():

    print("Welcome to Costa Tycoon!")
    print("------------------------")
    balance() 
    print(money)

def costa_tycoon():
    global money

    print("Welcome to Costa Tycoon!")
    print("------------------------")
    print("Hire worker for $50 (1)")
    print("------------------------")
    options = input()
    if options == '1':
        print("------------------------")
        balance()
        money += 50 
        print("Current Balance:", money)
```

in `balence()` by adding `global money`, money becomes a global variable which is used in `costa_tycoon()`

Comment: There isn't an actual global variable called `money` anywhere in the code, so I doubt that this will suffice (though I might be wrong, as I usually try to avoid having such variables to begin with).

Comment: i checked in jupitor it worked

Comment: @Mourya can you kindly explain your answer as it would help other understand how your resolve it when others are faced with the same challenge ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AbuGodda i did it